# How to test if value is in array PHP (key search)

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array in PHP:

```
$arr['key1']='value1';
$arr['key2']='value2';
$arr['key3']='value3';
$arr['key4']='value4';
$arr['key5']='value5';
$arr['key6']='value6';
```

I would like to test if a key is in the array. Is this function the correct way to proceed?

```
function isKeyInArray($key, $arr) {
   if(isset($arr[$key]))
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

What I expect is that:

```
isKeyInArray('key3', $arr) // return true
isKeyInArray('key9', $arr) // return false
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: so whats the problem? correct way to proceed? nothing wrong with this

Comment: How about testing it?

Comment: Why don't you use `array_key_exists()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `array_key_exists`.

```
$a=array("Volvo"=>"XC90","BMW"=>"X5");
if (array_key_exists("Volvo",$a))
  {
  echo "Key exists!";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Key does not exist!";
  }
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: @UBEX,This code will perform the task as well. But I'll recommend you to use the function you have written yourself as it will give you confidence to write code yourself instead asking here.

Answer (score 4):

Use [**array_key_exists**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
if(array_key_exists('key6',$arr))
   echo "present";
else
   echo "not present";
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `isset()` is good if you consider that `null` is not a suitable value. Also `isset` is faster than `array_key_exists`.

```
$a = [ 'one' => 1, 'two' => null ];
isset($a['one']); // true
isset($a['two']); // false
array_key_exists('two', $a); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php function `array_key_exists('key3', $a);`

First google your need and only after that you can use your own function. This will save lots of your time.